# $100(1-\alpha)$% approximate confidence interval

Tags: statistics

The question is:

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with density function $f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ for $0\leq x\leq\theta$ where $0<\theta$. What is a $100(1-\alpha)$% approximate confidence interval for $\theta$ if the sample size is large?

I know how to just find the confidence interval, but I'm not sure what to do if the sample size is large.

Answer (score 1):

The additional information about $n$ being large may imply they want the use of the central limit theorem. In any case, I get the impression that for this particular problem using the Uniform distribution the below confidence interval is probably your best bet even with 'large' data.

If $X_i\text{ iid}\sim U(\theta)$, and $X_{(n)}$ is the maximum value in your data set then consider $Q = \theta^{-1}X_{(n)}$.
$$\mathbb{P}(Q \leq t) = \prod_i \mathbb{P}(X_i\leq\theta t) = t^n$$
Notice that $\mathbb{P}(Q \leq 1) = 1$, and if we allow $a = \alpha^{1/n}$ then $\mathbb{P}(Q\leq a) = \alpha$ and
$$1 - \alpha = \mathbb{P}\left(a \leq Q \leq 1\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(a \leq\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta} \leq 1\right)$$ Solving for $\theta$ we get $$ \mathbb{P}\left(X_{(n)} \leq \theta \leq \frac{X_{(n)}}{a}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X_{(n)} \leq \theta \leq \frac{X_{(n)}}{\alpha^{1/n}}\right) = 1- \alpha$$

So a $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is $\left(X_{(n)}, \frac{X_{(n)}}{\alpha^{1/n}}\right)$